# When call method it returns empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension using VueJS. I store some data using `chrome.storage.sync` and I want to retrieve it later than iterate through it.

This is the code of the method that I use to get the data.

```js
getSpeedDials() {
  let speedDials = [] 
  chrome.storage.sync.get('speedDials', function(value)  { 
    if (value.hasOwnProperty('speedDials')) { 
      console.log(value.speedDials) 
      speedDials = value.speedDials 
    } 
  }); 
return speedDials 
}
```

The `console.log(value.speedDials)` outputs the expected result, an array that contains several objects. But the return is an empty array. How can I debug this?

Comment: I don't know this Chrome API, but I'm guessing it's async. If you log speedDials right before it's returned, I'd guess you see that being logged before the log inside the `get`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

return a promise from getSpeedDials function.

```
getSpeedDials() {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
   let speedDials = [] 
   chrome.storage.sync.get('speedDials', function(value)  { 
   if (value.hasOwnProperty('speedDials')) { 
     console.log(value.speedDials) 
     speedDials = value.speedDials;
     return resolve(speedDials);
   } 
   return resolve();
  // you can reject promise if you want to treat this as an error. 
  }); 
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.storage.sync.get` is async. You're returning the initial empty array before the values are loaded from the storage.

You can return a promise that resolves with the result when it's done.

```
async getSpeedDials() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('speedDials', result => {
            resolve(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that when you do this, getting the value should also be done differently.

Inside of an `async` function, we can use `await` to get the value:

```
let speedDials = await getSpeedDials();
```

If not:

```
let speedDials = [];
getSpeedDials().then(dials => {
    speedDials = dials
});
// Note that when doing this, everything under this function will be executed before speedDials has any entries.
// To prevent this, make your function async, and use the aforementioned method (await)
```

Let me know if you have any questions